# Spring boot Thymeleaf populate dropdown list based on other dropdown list selections

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I populate a dropdown list based on selections of other dropdown lists?

I have a `Unit` class, a `Size` class and a `City` class. The user must first select a country from a dropdown list of countries, the municipalities list will then display only the municipalities in that country, after that the user must select a city size, and at the end of it all, the user must select a city from a list of cities which are of the selected size, and belong to the selected municipality and country.

My code:

Unit.java

```
public class Unit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @ToString.Exclude
    private UnitType unitType;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Unit unit;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unit", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<City> cities;
}
```

UnitType.java

```
public class UnitType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UnitName uName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unitType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Unit> units;

    public enum UnitName {

        COUNTY, MUNICIPALITY
    }
}
```

CitySize.java

```
public class CitySize {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="naziv", nullable=false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Size name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "citySize", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<City> sizes;

    public enum Size {

        SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE
    }
}
```

City.java

```
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @ToString.Exclude
    private CitySize citySize;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Unit unit;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> events;
}
```

Event.java

```
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private LocalDateTime time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @ToString.Exclude
    private City city;

}
```

EventController.java

```
public class EventController {

    ....
    @GetMapping("/citySearch")
    public String citySearch(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("event", new Event());
        model.addAttribute("unit", new Unit());
        model.addAttribute("citySize", new CitySize());
        model.addAttribute("counties", unitRepository.findByUnitTypeId(50001L));
        model.addAttribute("municipalities", unitRepository.findByUnitTypeId(50002L));
        model.addAttribute("sizes", CitySize.Size.values());
        model.addAttribute("cities", cityRepository.findAll());

        return "citySearch";
    }

    @PostMapping("/citySearch")
    public String citySearch(Event event, Model model, City city, Unit unit,
        CitySize citySize) {

        List<Event> foundEvents = eventRepository.findByCity(city);
        model.addAttribute("unit", new Unit());
        model.addAttribute("citySize", new CitySize());
        model.addAttribute("counties", unitRepository.findByUnitTypeId(50001L));
        model.addAttribute("municipalities", unitRepository.findByUnitTypeId(50002L));
        model.addAttribute("sizes", CitySize.Size.values());
        model.addAttribute("cities", cityRepository.findAll());
        model.addAttribute("foundEvents", foundEvents);

        return "citySearch";
    }
}
```

citySearch.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" >

        <title>City search</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Event search by city</h1>

        <form th:object="${unit}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unit">County: </label>
                <select th:id="countyOption" th:field="*{unit}">
                    <option value="" >choose counties</option>
                    <option th:each="county : ${counties}" th:value="${county.id}" th:text="${county.name}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="unit">Municipality: </label>
                <select th:id="municipalityOption" th:field="*{unit}">
                    <option value="" >choose municipilaties</option>
                    <option th:each="municipality : ${municipilaties}" th:value="${municipality.id}" th:text="${municipality.name}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form th:object="${citySize}" method="post">

        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">City size: </label>
                <select th:field="*{name}">
                    <option value="" >choose a city size</option>
                    <option th:each="name : ${sizes}" th:value="${id}" th:text="${name}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form th:object="${event}" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city">City: </label>
                <select th:field="*{city}">
                    <option value="" >choose cities</option>
                    <option th:each="city : ${cities}" th:value="${city.id}" th:text="${city.name}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" th:value="Search">
        </form>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Time</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="event : ${foundEvents}">
                <td><span th:text="${event.name}" >EVENT.NAME</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${event.city.name}" >CITY.NAME</span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${#temporals.format(event.time, 'dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm')}" >EVENT.TIME</span></td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <p><a th:href="@{/search}">Return</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

So far, my web search provided information that this can't be done by using only Spring boot and Thymeleaf, only with jQuery. Since I don't know jQuery, I would require some instructions on how to write and implement the method in jQuery. Also, I don't have a WebConfig.java class, since I had no need for it so far in my app, but if I need it now, what does it have to contain?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot and Thymeleaf can't do anything client-side, but you can still achieve what you are trying to do without Javascript / JQuery:

You can submit the selected country to the backend, where you calculate the possible municipalities for that country, which you can add to the model and only display those (Or disable all other options). However, you will have to do that for every step that limits the options, that means reloading the page everytime, which can be painful to use.

If you want to accomplish the same without reloading the page, you will have to resort to some client-side code - that means Javascript / JQuery.

Comment: yes, I understand that, but how to do that using Javascript and jQuery?